# Java: ModelMapper does not compile data in nested collection lists

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, mapping, modelmapper

I have structure similar like this one below:

```
public class FirstObject {
    private List<SecondObject> myListOne;

    ...only getter method...
    ...no setter method for the list due to it is generated from wsdl 
}

public class SecondObject {
    private List<ThirdObject> myListTwo;

    ...only getter method...
    ...no setter method for the list due to it is generated from wsdl
}

public class ThirdObject {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    ...setters and getters...
}
```

The main issue are setter methods for the lists. If you try with PropertyMap or even with Providers you have to use setter methods and I cannot make them manually because all objects will be regenerated from wsdl each time when I run **mvn eclipse:eclipse** command.

**UPDATE**:

You can find my source code on following link:
https://github.com/ervinfetic/modelmapper-issue-one

**Is there any solution how to make this with Converter??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not able to have setters, you can configure `ModelMapper` to access by field. Just enable FieldMatching and the FieldAccessLevel as private like your list properties

```
modelMapper.getConfiguration()
  .setFieldMatchingEnabled(true)
  .setFieldAccessLevel(AccessLevel.PRIVATE);
```

Example:

Class `FirstObject`:

```
public class FirstObject {

    private String name;

    private List<FirstObjectList> objectList = new ArrayList<FirstObjectList>();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<FirstObjectList> getObjectList() {
        return objectList;
    }
}
```

Class `FirstObjectList`:

```
public class FirstObjectList {

    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

}
```

So we are looking to map `FirstObject` to our `SecondObject` class which has exactly the same structure (properties):

Class `SecondObject`:

```
public class SecondObject {

    private String name;

    private List<SecondObjectList> objectList;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<SecondObjectList> getObjectList() {
        return objectList;
    }

}
```

Class `SecondObjectList`:

```
public class SecondObjectList {

    private String id;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Then we need to create our ModelMapper instance and configure it as field matching and private access level.

```
public void test(){
    ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
    mapper.getConfiguration().setFieldMatchingEnabled(true);
    mapper.getConfiguration().setFieldAccessLevel(Configuration.AccessLevel.PRIVATE);


    FirstObject firstObject = new FirstObject();
    firstObject.setName("Hola");

    FirstObjectList firstObjectList = new FirstObjectList();
    firstObjectList.setId("1");

    firstObject.getObjectList().add(firstObjectList);

    SecondObject second = mapper.map(firstObject, SecondObject.class);

    assertEquals(firstObject.getName(), second.getName());

    assertEquals(firstObject.getObjectList().size(), second.getObjectList().size());    
    assertEquals(firstObject.getObjectList().get(0).getId(), second.getObjectList().get(0).getId());
}
```

All has been mapped perfectly. So it works.

- Output:

> SecondObject{name='Hola', objectList=[SecondObjectList{id='1'}]}

But if haven't enabled `FieldMatching` or set the Field Access Level as Private your list won't be mapped:

- Output:

> SecondObject{name='Hola', objectList=null}

#### UPDATE

If you have nested lists you mayset the naming convention as mutators to avoid multiple matching error, just configuring it like next:

```
 modelMapper.getConfiguration()
.setSourceNamingConvention(NamingConventions.JAVABEANS_MUTATOR);
```

---

Otherwise, if you don't want to do it by field access, you can create a `Converter` to handle this kind of matching:

```
public class ListConverter implements Converter<List<SecondObject>, List<ThirdObject>> {

    @Override
    public List<ThirdObject> convert(MappingContext<List<SecondObject>, List<PromoConditionEntity>> context) {
       //A java 8 mapping example
       return context.getSource()
          .stream()
          .map(this::convertToThirdObject)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    private ThirdObject convertToThirdObject(SecondObject s) {
       //your impl map SecondObject to ThirdObject
       ...
     }
}
```

Finally, Don't forget to add the converter to your modelmapper isntance:

```
modelMapper.addConverter(new ListConverter());
```

Comment: Your response make sense. I will try it asap. It would be great if this example works.

Comment: I've got the solution to your error just add: `modelMapper.getConfiguration().setSourceNamingConvention(NamingConventions.JAVABEANS_MUTATOR)` set the access with set and disable getter access.;